# Can a Map value reference another value in the same Map?

Tags: dictionary, dart

Can a value in a Dart `Map` reference another value in the same `Map`?

For example

```
Map<String, String> map = {
    'data': {
        'default': 'some default value',
        'value1':       'some value',
        'value2':       'some other value',
        'value3':       map['data']['default'] // Is this possible??
    }
};
```

If I do it like above, I get

```
The following CyclicInitializationError was thrown building MainPage:
  Reading static variable 'map' during its initialization
```

Of course I could create the default value as a separate variable, but I'd prefer not to. Is there a neat way to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this on [dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/)

```
void main() {
  Map<String, Map<String, String>> map = {
    'data': {
      'default': 'some default value',
      'value1': 'some value',
      'value2': 'some other value',
    }
  };

  map['data']['value3'] = map['data']['default'];

  print(map['data']);
}
```